# C++ declaring variable inside if statement

Tags: c++, declaration

I have a really basic problem in c++, I'm reading a tab separated file and I want to declare an array with the dimension if the number of fields the file has (work with different files with different widths) so I need to read the first line and count the number of fields, I tried this:

```
while(getline(t, line));{
...
if(!flag)
{int array[size][5];
flag=1}
...
}
```

But then I get the error:

error:  'array' was not declared in this scope

I understand it is because the scope of the variable is in the if loop, is there any way to declare a null array and resize it? Or will I have to use pointers?

Comment: did you try alloc malloc calloc to a pointer in the if block?

Comment: Use `std::vector`. BTW, that `while` will read all of the lines in the file before progressing to the `if()` due to the trailing semi-colon at then of the `while`.

Comment: Why use pointers when you have std::vector? Try doing things the easy way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The size of an array must be a compile-time constant. Use a `std::vector` if you want a dynamically-sized array.

Other issues with your code:

1. Remove the semicolon after the `while`, or your loop body will only be executed once after the whole file is read.
2. Add a semicolon after `flag=1`.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, that was super sloppy. Size is  the number of columns I have (didnt post all the code because im using boost) . I would like to use vectors, the problem in that this will end up being a 4 dimensional array, wich some columns will be empty. So It is my understanding that vectors are not allowed to have empty spaces. For example I will have row number 256 and fill that row, without knowing if whoch rows from 0-256 even exist.

Comment: @Jorge: Arrays can't have empty spaces either, so there's no difference in that regard. If you use e.g. `myvector.resize(257)` then new rows will be added as needed with default values.

Comment: ok, that actually makes a lot of sense, now I feel kinda dumb for thinking about resizing vector, thnx!

Answer (score 4):

You are writing C++, so why not use a `std::vector<std::vector<int> >`? If possible (here it is) try not to use raw pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Pointers will be the way to go...

Comment: No, pointers are error prone. `std::vector` is a much better solution in C++

Comment: 'Dynamic arrays' are a better way to describe arrays allocated based on a runtime size than just 'pointers'.  But as as other pointed out std::vector are the way to go...

Answer (score 0):

int array[size] possible just in C99.
In C++ plain-C array sizes should be compile-time constant.